# OpenJDK 7 2011 port for FreeBSD 6.3

Tags: freebsd, java

I am trying to run a propriety code of **Java 7 with features introduced in late 2010** on **FreeBSD 6.3** using the **openjdk-7.0.117.tbz** from http://ftp.riken.jp/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-6-stable/java/

However, I am seeing some incompatibilities in the code and the Java version. The code uses some features introduces in late 2010 of Java 7 which are not present in the version of Java I am using like some of the Files feature.

Does anyone have access to a **FreeBSD 6.3 OpenJDK 7 post 2010** port which I can use.

I have already tried running the FreeBSD 7 version ports on 6.3 machines but am facing some libc++.so issues. I have used many other openjdk versions from http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/mirror/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/i386/ but to no avail.

Can someone guide me in this regards, I can't change my platform from 6.3 which is probably the bottleneck in my case. Can someone point me to a **Freebsd 6.3 port of openjdk 7 binaries or source code after 2010**

Answer (score 0):

You may try the packages under packages-current, later versions are available and probably compile on 6.3 
[Riken Current Package Repository](http://ftp.riken.jp/pub/FreeBSD/ports/i386/packages-current/java/)
. You are unable to compile on the older versions because you might need to update the libc++ libraries which are required by the older versions.